# Combined Event Handling of widgets in TKinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a GUI Program in Tkinter and am running into problems.What I want to do is draw 2 checkboxes and a button. According to the user input next steps should take place. A part of my code has been shown below :-

```
CheckVar1 = IntVar()
CheckVar2 = IntVar()
self.C1 = Checkbutton(root, text = "C Classifier", variable = CheckVar1, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=5,width = 20).grid(row=4)

self.C2 = Checkbutton(root, text = "GClassifier", variable = CheckVar2, onvalue = 1,    offvalue = 0, height=5, width = 20).grid(row=5)

self.proceed1 = Button(root,text = "\n Proceed",command =       self.proceed(CheckVar1.get(),CheckVar2.get())).grid(row=6)

# where proceed prints the combined values of 2 checkboxes
```

The error that I am getting is typical ie a default value of both the selected checkboxes gets printed up and then there is no further input. The error that I get is NullType Object is not callable.

I searched on the net and I think the answer is related to lambda events or curry.

Please help ..

Comment: Please note that `Checkbutton(…)` evaluates to a Checkbutton, while `Checkbutton(…).grid(…)` evaluates to None; why do you store None to self.C1, self.C2 and self.proceed1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the *value* of  `self.proceed(CheckVar1.get(),CheckVar2.get())` to the `Button` constructor, but presumably what you want is for `command` to be set to a *function* which will call `self.proceed(CheckVar1.get(),CheckVar2.get())` and return a new, possibly different value every time the button is pressed. You can fix that with a lambda, or by wrapping the call in a short callback function. For example, replace the last line with:

```
def callback():
    return self.proceed(CheckVar1.get(), CheckVar2.get())
self.proceed1 = Button(root, text="\n Proceed", command=callback).grid(row=6)
```

This is pretty typical Tkinter. Remember: when you see a variable called `command` in Tkinter, it's looking for a *function*, not a value.

EDIT: to be clear: you're getting 'NullType Object is not callable' because you've set `command` to equal the return value of a single call to `self.proceed` (that's the NullType Object). `self.proceed` is a function, but its return value is not. What you need is to set `command` to be a function which calls `self.proceed`.

Comment: Hey, really sorry it's my mistake as it was'nt clear from the code. self.proceed is a function that takes these as input and prints the values...

Comment: That doesn't change my answer. Your code currently calls `self.proceed` once, and sets `command` to equal the *value* of `self.proceed`, when you want to set `command` to a *function* which calls `self.proceed` every time the button is pressed.

Comment: Hey Thanks my error has gone but I fail to get the result what I want. In this I want to operate on the values of CheckVar1 and CheckVar2. How can I do it. I think that my understanding was wrong.

Comment: Isn't the values of checkboxes automatically set when they are sselected. Then why would I change them. What I want is that I use chechboxes to get the values (0,0) ,(0,1),(1,0),(1,1) the combinations of these checkbox selections. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Like Peter Milley said, the `command` option needs a reference to a function (ie: give it a function *name* (ie: no parenthesis). Don't try to "inline" something, create a special function.  Your code will be easier to understand and to maintain.